# Duplication detection for 3K incoming requests per second, recommended data structure/algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, servlets, data-structures, concurrency

Designing a system where a service endpoint (probably a simple servlet) will have to handle 3K requests per second (data will be http posted).

These requests will then be stored into mysql.

**They key issue that I need guidance on is that their will be a high % of duplicate data posted to this endpoint.**

I only need to store unique data to mysql, so what would you suggest I use to handle the duplication?

The posted data will look like:

```
<root>
<prop1></prop1>
<prop2></prop2>
<prop3></prop3>
<body>
maybe 10-30K of test in here
</body>
</root>
```

I will write a method that will hash prop1, prop2, pro3 to create a unique hashcode (body can be different and still be considered unique).

*I was thinking of creating some sort of concurrent dictionary that will be shared accross requests.*

**Their are more chances of duplication of posted data within a period of 24 hours**. So I can purge data from this dictionary after every x hours.

Any suggestions on the data structure to store duplications?  And what about purging and how many records I should store considering 3K requests per second i.e. it will get large very fast.

Note:  Their are 10K different sources that will be posting, and the chances of duplication only occurrs for a given source.  Meaning I could have more than one dictionary for maybe a group of sources to spread things out.  Meaning if source1 posts data, and then source2 posts data, the changes of duplication are very very low.  But if source1 posts 100 times in a day, the chances of duplication are very high.

**Note: please ignore for now the task of saving the posted data to mysql as that is another issue on its own, duplication detection is my first hurdle I need help with.**

Comment: doesn't sql have dupe detection

Comment: Is it only the prop field at the start which need to be checked?

Comment: The "obvious" solution is to use the DB to detect the duplicates. Before inventing other mechanisms, how many orders of magnitude too slow is that?

Comment: @Steve I don't want to use a db since that means the 30K has to cross the wire to the db server.  I have the posted data on hand, I want to handle it right there.  remember 3K per second is tons of traffic.

Comment: I didn't say, "do you want to use the DB for this?", I said "how fast/slow is the trivial version that does use the DB for this?". I agree that 90MB/s is a lot of traffic, but is it 10 times what your setup can handle? 1000 times?

Comment: Can you afford losing some data because of false positives in duplicate detection?

Comment: @blaze: and if not, it becomes important whether data is ever removed from the DB. If data can be removed from the DB, and false positives on the dupe detection are unacceptable, then it's essential that all caches in front of the DB are purged immediately (if not before) of any entries removed from the DB.

Comment: @blaze no, that seems to be the problem with bloom filters.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

I would probably be looking at some kind of HashMap of HashMaps structure here where the first level of HashMaps would use the sources as keys and the second level would contain the actual data (the minimal for detecting duplicates) and use your hashcode function for hashing. For actual implementation, Java's ConcurrentHashMap would probably be the choice.

This way you have also set up the structure to partition your incoming load depending on sources if you need to distribute the load over several machines.

With regards to purging I think you have to measure the exact behavior with production like data. You need to learn how quickly the data grows when you successfully eliminate duplicates and how it becomes distributed in the HashMaps. With a good distribution and a not too quick growth I can imagine it is good enough to do a cleanup occasionally. Otherwise maybe a LRU policy would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a hashing structure that can add and check the existence of a key in constant time. In that case, try to implement a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Be careful that this is a probabilistic structure i.e. it may tell you that a key exists when it does not, but you can make the probability of failure extremely low if you tweak the parameters carefully.

**Edit**: Ok, so bloom filters are not acceptable. To still maintain constant lookup (albeit not a constant insertion), try to look into [Cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

Comment: I could afford to insert when in fact it was a dup, but I can't afford to ignore it if it says it was a dup when in fact it was unique.

Comment: Cuckoo hashing is an improvement on regular hashing for a hashtable; if the correct solution is a hashtable, it's probably better to just use one that's already built than to build your own - certainly before assessing if that's necessary.

Comment: The problem is that he needs a hash which can determine in constant time if a key exists or not. I'm not sure how regular hashes are implemented, but if they use chaining then it's not a good idea.

Comment: Do an md5 hash of your props and then use a counting-bloom-filter (https://www.google.com/search?q=counting+bloom+filter) to maintain stats

Answer (score 1):

**1) Setup your database like this**

```
ALTER TABLE Root ADD UNIQUE INDEX(Prop1, Prop2, Prop3);

INSERT INTO Root (Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Body) VALUES (@prop1, @prop2, @prop3, @body) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Body=@body
```

**2) You don't need any algorithms or fancy hashing ADTs**

```
shell> mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html
Make use of the --replace or --ignore flags, as well as, --compress.

**3) All your Java will do is...**

a) generate CSV files, use the StringBuffer class then every X seconds or so, swap with a fresh StringBuffer and pass the .toString of the old one to a thread to flush it to a file /temp/SOURCE/TIME_STAMP.csv

b) occasionally kick off a Runtime.getRuntime().exec of the mysqlimport command

c) delete the old CSV files if space is an issue, or archive them to network storage/backup device

Answer (score 0):

Well you're basically looking for some kind of extremely large Hashmap and something like

`if (map.put(key, val) != null) // send data`

There are lots of different Hashmap implementations available, but you could look at [NBHM](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/javadoc/concjunit4.7/org/cliffc/high_scale_lib/NonBlockingHashMap.html#put%28TypeK,%20TypeV%29). Non-blocking puts and designed with large, scalable problems in mind could work just fine. The Map also has iterators that do NOT throw a ConcurrentModificationException while using them to traverse the map which is basically a requirement for removing old data as I see it. Also `putIfAbsent` is all you actually need - but no idea if that's more efficient than just a simple put, you'd have to ask Cliff or check the source.

The trick then is to try to avoid resizing of the Map by making it large enough - otherwise the throughput will suffer while resizing (which could be a problem). And think about how to implement the removing of old data - using some idle thread that traverses an iterator and removes old data probably.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.util.ConcurrentHashMap` for building a map of your hashes, but make sure you have the correct initialCapacity and concurrencyLevel assigned to the map at creation time.

The [api docs for ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap%28int,%20float,%20int%29) have all the relevant information:

> *initialCapacity* - the initial capacity. The implementation performs
> internal sizing to accommodate this many elements.
>
> *concurrencyLevel* - the estimated number of concurrently updating threads. The
> implementation performs internal sizing to try to accommodate this
> many threads.

You should be able to use putIfAbsent for handling 3K requests as long as you have initialized the ConcurrentHashMap the right way - make sure this is tuned as part of your load testing.

At some point, though, trying to handle all the requests in one server may prove to be too much, and you will have to load-balance across servers. At that point you may consider using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for storing the index of hashes, instead of the CHP.

The interesting problems that you will still have to solve, though, are:

- loading all of the hashes into memory at startup
- determining when to knock off hashes from the in-memory map

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **strong hash formula**, such as MD5 or SHA-1, **you will not need to store any data at all**. The probability of duplicate is virtually null, so if you find the same hash result twice, the second is a duplicate.
Given that MD5 is 16 bytes, and SHA-1 20 bytes, it should decrease memory requirements, therefore keeping more elements in the CPU cache, therefore dramatically improving speed.

Storing these keys requires little else than a small hash table followed by trees to handle collisions.

Comment: you mean store the hashes in memory?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Memory should be checked, since 20 bytes per request still translates into 20MB of memory for 1 million (different) requests. But you get the idea.